# Enumerating StarTeam projects via stcmd.exe

Tags: enumeration, extract, starteam

Before I get into the nitty-gritty of what I am looking for, I'd like to take a moment and focus on the background so that the big picture will (hopefully) be clear for all of you.
 I'll start with my stated goal, my current method for achieving it, and where I'm stuck at.

**Goal:** Extract all subdirectories from any view of every StarTeam project located in an arbitrary StarTeam server.

So far, I've had particular luck using **stcmd.exe**

```
// lets me see what I'm about to check out  
.\stcmd list -short -p "username:password@domain.com:1024/projectName" -is "*"

// checks out all files contained in the specified view
.\stcmd co -p "username:password@domain.com:1024/projectName/view1.2.3" -is "*"
```

To be honest, I'm *almost* there. My difficulty is that I do not know ahead of time what views may exist under a particular StarTeam project. I am looking for a programmatic way of obtaining a list of views for projects, so I can **enumerate** them via powershell or what have you.

Does that make sense? I just don't want to have to manually look at each project and run stcmd.exe to check out each view. It must be automated!

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are curious, I was able to get this done by using the StarTeam SDK to find out the list of projects and views, and then call stcmd.exe to check out each one.